# tag-it selection issue using mouse on bootstrap modal pop up

Tags: bootstrap-4, tag-it

I have two forms use tag-it auto complete. One sit in a page, and one in modal box. Both are calling the same array list and have same target class. The one in the page works beautifully. However, the one in modal box has weird issue: when I use mouse to select tag from drop down list, it always put first letter in the input box with highlight but I am able to select item using down arrow key.

May I request for any solution for the same.

Answer (score 0):

do you have a sample of your code please to have a look at it ?
Can do nothing without it :)